# ERC20 totalSupply always returns 0

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I've deployed an ERC20 token on the main net that you can find on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0x47010bfcdebde5c6f0cb3426cee269a96f7ac6ce#code).

The problem I'm having, as you can see on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/token/0x47010bfcdebde5c6f0cb3426cee269a96f7ac6ce), is that totalSupply always returns 0, even if I've already minted 6M+ tokens.

This is the ABI for the totalSupply function:

```
[{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "totalSupply",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}]
```

Defined in Solidity as:

```
uint256 public totalSupply;
```

and initialised in the main contract with:

```
uint256 public totalSupply = 0;
```

I don't understand if totalSupply is correctly stored internally and it's just a problem when getting the value from outside, or if the smart contract is actually not adding the minted tokens to the totalSupply.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: this is the minting function (the rest of the code is uploaded and verified on etherscan):

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    totalSupply = SafeMath.add(totalSupply, _amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    emit Mint(_to, _amount);
    emit Transfer(0x0, _to, _amount);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How do you mint? Is the minting supposed to increase your `totalSupply` variable?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to increase the totalSupply variable. I've added the relevant code in the question, but you can find the whole contract on etherscan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging I found your problem.

You are redeclaring the variable `totalSupply` in your custom token code. This overrides the variable from `BasicToken` contract and the variable's value is set to 0.

When you call the `mint` function it can't modify the value of `totalSupply` from your custom token because it's higher in the inheritance chain so it modifies the variable in `BasicToken`. I guess in theory if you then looked at the value in `BasicToken` you'd see the right value but you are always interacting with your custome token so you always see the value which is there.

Just remove the variable declaration from your custom token contract and it works just fine.